# no such table:@DatabseView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, sqliteopenhelper

I was trying to create a database view in android but getting this error:

> error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
>   missing database (no such table: ChatsView)
>       public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData>
>   getMessageViewLIst();

Please help me with this that how can i get data from a DatabaseView in room persistence android

> DatabaseView Class

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT chats.username as username," +
    "(SELECT chat.message FROM ChatEntityModel as chat WHERE chat.username=chats.username ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as lastMsg" +
    "(SELECT chat.timeStamp FROM ChatEntityModel as chat WHERE chat.username=chats.username ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as lastMsgTime " +
    "(SELECT count(1) FROM ChatEntityModel as chat WHERE chat.username=chats.username and status=4 ) as totalNewMsgCount From ChatEntityModel as chats",viewName = "ChatsView")
data class ChatsView (
        val username:String,
        val lastMsg:String,
        val lastMsgTime:String,
        val totalNewMsgCount:String
)
```

> Entity Class

```
@Entity(tableName = "ChatEntityModel")
data class ChatEntityModel (


@ColumnInfo(name = "message") var KEY_MESSAGE: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "username") var KEY_USERNAME : String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "msgsend") var KEY_MSG_SEND : Boolean,
@ColumnInfo(name = "timeStamp") var KEY_TIMESTAMP :String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "status") var KEY_STATUS :Int,
@ColumnInfo(name = "msgid") var KEY_MSG_ID :String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp_delivered") var KEY_TIME_DELIVERED :String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp_read") var KEY_TIME_READ :String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "progress") var KEY_PROGRESS :String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "type") var KEY_TYPE : String


){
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)@ColumnInfo(name = "id")var KEY_ID:Int=0
}
```

> DaoAccess class

```
@Database(entities = [(ChatEntityModel::class)], views = [(ChatsView::class)], version = 1, 
exportSchema = false)
abstract class DaoDatabaseAccess:RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun ChattingDao():ChattingDao
//    abstract fun ChattViewDao():ChattViewDao


}
```

> Dao

```
@Dao
interface ChattingDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
fun insertChatList(chats: List<ChatEntityModel>)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
fun inserChat(chats: ChatEntityModel)

@Update
fun updateMovie(chats: ChatEntityModel)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE id = :id_")
fun getMovie(id_: Int): ChatEntityModel

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE username=:Jid ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getChatList(Jid:String?): LiveData<List<ChatEntityModel>>

@Query("Update  ChatEntityModel SET status=2 , timestamp_delivered=:timeDelivered WHERE msgid=:msg_id 
and status <> 3  and username=:Jid ")
fun setChatDelivered(timeDelivered: String?,msg_id:String?,Jid: String?)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE status=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1" )
fun getUnsentMessage(): List<ChatEntityModel>

@Query("SELECT msgid FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE status=4 and username=:username ORDER BY id" )
fun getUnReadMessage(username:String): List<String>

@Query("UPDATE ChatEntityModel SET status=1 WHERE msgid= :msgId and status=0")
fun setMessageSent(msgId: String?)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE msgid =:msgId")
fun checkIfExists(msgId:String?): List<ChatEntityModel>

@Query("Update  ChatEntityModel SET status=3 , timestamp_read=:currentTimeMillis WHERE msgid in (:receiptId) and username=:Jid ")
fun setChatRead(currentTimeMillis: String?, receiptId:List<String>,Jid: String?)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatEntityModel WHERE  status=4 and username=:Jid ")
fun getUnReadChats(Jid: String?):LiveData<List<ChatEntityModel>>

@Query("UPDATE ChatEntityModel set status=5 WHERE  status=4 and  msgid in (:chat) ")
fun setChatReceivedRead(chat:List<String>)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ChatsView")
fun getMessageViewLIst(): LiveData<List<ChatsView>>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not related to your problem, but maybe it is, sometimes errors are weird. The request of your View as several `SELECT` which isn't correct, maybe try fixing your `Query`.

EDIT: For more clarity, the issue is that the `Query` was wrong and was missing  comas.

Comment: query is good i have tried same query with in dao without using view but i want do this using DatabseView at that time i am getting this error that no such table exists

Comment: isn't some comma missing ? after `as lastMsg` and after `as lastMsgTime` ? I've created a View on my project, and added it on the DAO and database as you did, everything worked directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **database name** to the **abstract RoomDatabase class**

```
@Database(entities = [ChatsView::class], version = 1)
abstract class DaoDatabaseAccess:RoomDatabase() {

}
```